# Problems while changing to class views in Django

Tags: django, python-2.6, django-class-based-views, django-1.4

I am trying to change to class-based views in Django after an upgrade and I have two questions regarding this. This is my code, simplified:

```
# urls.py

urlpatterns += patterns('project.app.views',
    ('^$', 'index'), # Old style
    url(r'^test/$', SearchView.as_view()), # New style
)


# views.py

class SearchView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'search.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        messages.success(request, 'test')
        return {'search_string': 'Test'}
```

When I run this I first get the error `name 'SearchView' is not defined`. Does anyone know why?

Trying to skip that I add `from project.app.views import SearchView` which is ugly and not the way I want it to work, but hey, I try to see if I can get the rest working. Then I get `global name 'request' is not defined` because of the `messages`. This makes sense but how do I get the request object here?

So I'd like to know: how do I get the views to work as intended and how to use messages in `get_context_data()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing `name 'SearchView' is not defined` because you have not imported `SearchView` into your `urls.py`. If you think this is ugly then you can do `search = SearchView.as_view()` in your `views.py` and use the old style to reference the view as `search` instead. The request can be accessed on `self.request` for adding the messages. The updated source example is given below.

```
# views.py
class SearchView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'search.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        messages.success(self.request, 'test')
        return {'search_string': 'Test'}

search = SearchView.as_view()

# urls.py
urlpatterns += patterns('project.app.views',
    url('^$', 'index'), # Old style
    url(r'^test/$', 'search'), # New style
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed that request is in self. I thought that Django would find my SearchView class from 'project.app.views' in patterns as it does with the old style functions. I find it strange that it doesn't.

Comment: Without the import your original `urls.py` isn't valid Python. Not much Django can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

Please ask a single question at a time (a StackOverflow guideline).

Anyway:

- **This is the way class-based views are intended to work**. There's no auto-importing magic, you just import the class and use its as_view() method.
- You can access the request object in your view class through `self.request`.

Comment: The first is correct, but the second is not. All class-based views set the request as `self.request`, which can be accessed from anywhere including `get_context_data`. You shouldn't override `dispatch` unless you actually need to change the dispatch functionality.